# Iterable.forEach(Consumer)

Tags: java, foreach

I'm trying to comprehend why the following code snippet doesn't work as expected. I suspect it's because of immutability of Integer class but it's not clear exactly. Could you please explain it to me?

```
    List<Integer> a1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4);
    a1.forEach(integer -> integer += 10);
```

Comment: Can you define what you are expecting and what you are getting?

Comment: It is same problem as in case of `for(int value : list){value = value + 10;}`.

Comment: @Philibobby see erickson's answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
a1.replaceAll(integer -> integer + 10);
```

`Integer` objects are immutable. `integer += 10` means

```
integer = Integer.valueOf(integer.intValue() + 10);
```

Since `integer` is a local variable, the result is discarded when the `Consumer` returns.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very similar to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<a1.size(); i++){
    int integer = a1.get(i);
    integer = integer + 10;
}
```

Just because you updated value of local variable `integer` (which holds current element from list), it doesn't mean you updated value in list itself.

You can also think of it as

```
int a = 10; 
int b = a;
b = 20;
```

just because we changed value of `b` it doesn't mean we changed also value of `a`.

If you are looking for method which will update all values from list according to some function use `replaceAll` method added as [pointed by erickson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33679301/1393766).